# How to style text in JQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, css, text, styling

I want to make part of my text Bold and bigger than another part of text. But currently with the jquery I'm using the text all turns out the same size, font weight and colour. For example from my first bit on code bellow I want "Hard drive: Secondary Storage Device" to appear. I want Hard Drive to be in bold writing and the header. I want the other half normal font weight an smaller. How do I style this in jquery or css with the code I have?:)

If you can help it would be really appreciated!

Here is my j query:

```
$('#harddrive').hover(function() {
$('#info').text('Hard drive: Secondary Storage Device');
}, function() {
$('#info').text('');
});

$('#cd').hover(function() {
$('#info').text('CD: External Secondary Storage Device');
}, function() {
$('#info').text('');
});

$('#fan').hover(function() {
$('#info').text('Fan: Used to keep the computer cool');
}, function() {
$('#info').text('');
});

$('#powerblock').hover(function() {
$('#info').text('Power Block: Provides power to the computer');
}, function() {
$('#info').text('');
});
```

Comment: use `.html()` instead of `.text()` and wrap the text, then just style using css?

Comment: Thanks a million :) Had completely looked over it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to change the HTML and use `.html()` and not `.text()`.

For example:

```
$('#info').html('<h3>Hard drive:</h3> Secondary Storage Device');
```

Comment: Great thanks a million :) had completely overlooked it!!

Answer (score 5):

Use `.html()` instead of `.text()` if you want to style your text.

Here is an example:

```
$('#harddrive').hover(function() {
$('#info').html('<h3><b>Hard drive:</b></h3> Secondary Storage Device');
}, function() {
$('#info').html('');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't, as long as you're only using plain text as the content. Use HTML instead, and you can style the header as you please:

```js
$('#cd').hover(
  function() {
    $('#info').html('<span class="header">CD:</span> External Secondary Storage Device');
  }, 
  function() {
    $('#info').empty();
  });
```

```css
.header {
  font-size: larger;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a id="cd" href="#">CD</a>

<div id=info></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like

```
$('#info').html('<b>Hard drive</b>: Secondary Storage Device');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use JQuery's `$('#info').css()`. Using `$('#info').css(propertyName)` you can retrieve the value of a CSS property, or you can use `$('#info').css(propertyName, value)` to set it.

If you want your text to be bold, use `$('#info').css('font-weight', 'bold')`.

Answer (score 0):

Create a class on CSS

```
.bold{
font-weight:bold;
}
```

and then add the class to the #info only on the hover function that you want

```
$( "#info" ).addClass( "bold" );
```